# How to Set Command Timeout in dapper globally

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dapper

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project which uses Dapper. I have around 100 repositories in which Dapper is used. I want to set a command timeout now, one way is specifying individually on every Dapper query like this:

```
commandTimeout: TimeoutInSeconds
```

But that's very time consuming and not a good practice.

Is there anyway we can set command timeout globally in Dapper?

Comment: you can do it on connection object, for example by creating proper connection string.

Comment: you mean in connection string? that would be connection timeout not command timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set it globally in dapper (just call it at the very beggining of your app):

```
Dapper.SqlMapper.Settings.CommandTimeout = 100;
```

Comment: Connection string does not have commandTimeout: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Thanks for the other solution that works.

Comment: True, there is nothing like 'CommandTimeout' in connection string in ADO.NET- I was in too much of a hurry, sorry. Im glad that second one worked. I have modified my answer.